# I can't understand what's happening here ,when i tried to run my mongodb server , it shows this type of error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is the program for MongoDB server:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const dbname = "student_mongodb";
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const mongoOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true };
const state = 
{
  db: null
};
const connect = (cb) => {
   if (state.db) 
     cb();
   else {
     MongoClient.connect(url, mongoOptions, (err, client) => {
        if (err) cb(err);
        else {
            state.db = client.db(dbname);
            cb();
        }
    });
  }
}

const getPrimaryKey = (_id) => 
{
  return ObjectID(_id);
}
const getDB = () => 
{
  return state.db;
}
module.exports = { getDB, connect, getPrimaryKey };
```

And I am getting this:

(node:6320) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true
} to the MongoClient constructor.
unable to connect to database

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. It should still work - it's just a notification to let you know you can use a new version.

Answer (score 2):

just pass `useUnifiedTopology: true` to your options. it's a warning and not an error your app should be working fine.

```
const mongoOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
```